# Python 3, TypeError '>' , conversion from 2.7 to 3

Tags: python-3.x

New to Python here, attempting to update someone elses code from python 2.7 to 3.  I ran 2to3 on this file, and it worked fine with 2.7, but appears that the syntax has changed in 3? What is wrong with this syntax causing the error? I suspect that the error message related to '>' has something to do with the max request? This is running in a jupyter notebook with anaconda and python 3.7.

```
~/jam2py3/simulation.py in get_max_age(model)
     12 def get_max_age(model):
     13   all_compartments = model.select_compartments(lambda c: True)
---> 14   oldest = max(all_compartments, key=lambda c: c.get_attr('age'))
     15   return oldest.get_attr('age')
     16 

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Use `c.get_attr('age', 0)` ?

Comment: It's going to be hard to say anything specific without a [mcve], but it's probably going to be hard to create a [mcve] to begin with, so here goes my guessing: There's no attribute `age` in one or more of the objects in the `all_compartments` list, or the list is empty. That cause the comparison between the "age" to fail since both sides of the `>` comparison is `None`.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, presume you mean to line 14?

Comment: @Rakesh, I added that to line 14 and now get error "TypeError: get_attr() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"